# Is there a way to substring a C macro agrument and call different functions based on its name?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

for example:

```
#define PRINT(var) do { \
    print_##var[2..] (var); \
} while(0)
        
void print_foo(int foo)
{
    // some code
}

void print_bar(int bar)
{
    // some code
}

int main()
{
    int x_foo;
    int y_bar;
    
    PRINT(x_foo); // should call print_foo
    
    PRINT(y_bar); // should call print_bar
}
```

What I mean by the line `print_##var[2..]` is I want to glue to `print_` the argument `var` but substringed from 2 to its length. Such that `x_foo` turns into `foo` and the function `print_foo` is called.

Is something like this possible in C?

Comment: You're asking a macro to behave differently based on runtime data. Not going to happen. What you need is a *function look-up table* with your prefixes and function pointers.

Comment: No this is absolutely impossible.

Comment: @tadman not runtime data. The argument name is known at compile time

Comment: Not with the way you've defined it here, you're manipulating runtime data structures.

Comment: A) Why are the first three letters of `var` important? B) Why can't this be called with just the prefix required? C) Why not just call the print_XYZ function directly instead of going though this bizarre ceremony?

Comment: @tadman yes, but I don't have to. The information is all there for the compiler, all it needs is the macro argument name (known at compile time) and to substring it (can be derived at compile time), and then use the substring to call a function. At its core this can be a compile time operation.

Comment: The information is *not* there for the compiler. You're asking it to generate run-time code. It's doing that. You're then asking to use the run-time code to direct the pre-processor, but at that point it's long dead. In a language like Rust which does have compiled macros, yes, you can do this. Unfortunately, C has no such support.

Comment: @tadman the reason I wrote char* and called runtime funcs is to show my intention and explain what I want. I don't mean to say this is exactly how I want it. I'm simply wondering if the core problem has a solution. Can I substring a macro argument and use that substring to call a different function

Comment: Remember, the pre-processor runs before the compiler and *does not run after*. It has one shot to do what it needs to do, and then get out of the way. It has no ability to compile code and evaluate output.

Comment: Answer: **No**. This is often solved by using some kind of code-generator external to C, or by building some custom tool that is then used to generate code.

Comment: @i486 Oh I understand C, I was just wondering if there's a new feature I didn't learn about that allows to decompose a macro argument (simple thing really, might even be added in the future)

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi The language is not used in this way. Even if such feature exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to substring a C macro agrument call different functions based on its name?

No.

You can dispatch on runtime with prepared map.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
void print_foo(int foo) {
    // some code
}
void print_bar(int bar) {
    // some code
}

struct {
   const char *name;
   void (*func)(int);
} map[] = {
    { "foo", print_foo, },
    { "bar", print_bar, },
};

void PRINT(const char *name, int val) {
    assert(name);
    assert(strlen(name) > 2);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(map)/sizeof(*map); ++i) {
         if (strcmp(map[i].name, &name[2]) == 0) {
             map[i].func(val);
         }
     }
    assert(!!"Invalid name");
}

#define PRINT(x)  PRINT(#x, x)

int main() {
    int x_foo;
    int y_bar;
    PRINT(x_foo); // should call print_foo
    PRINT(y_bar); // should call print_bar
}
```

You can use a better preprocessor on top of C like m4, jinja2, php or other. For example:

```
// m4 file | cc -xc - && ./a.out
define(`PRINT', `print_`'substr($1, 2)($1)')
void print_foo(int foo) {
    // some code
}
void print_bar(int bar) {
    // some code
}
int main() {
    int x_foo;
    int y_bar;
    PRINT(x_foo); // should call print_foo
    PRINT(y_bar); // should call print_bar
}
```

In C programming language, however, typically, you would write `print_foo` and `print_bar` into the source code yourself. A dispatch depending on the name of a variable is confusing and will result in hard to debug and maintain source code.

Answer (score 3):

You can not "decompose" a variable name into `foo` and `x` part, but you can re-compose it, like so:

```
#define PRINT(var1, var2) do { \
    print_##var1 (var2##_##var1); \
} while(0)

int main() { ...
  PRINT(foo, x);  // expands to print_foo(x_foo)
  PRINT(bar, y);  // expands to print_bar(y_bar)
```

Please don't write code like that -- it's a nightmare to maintain.

There are usually better solutions to whatever problem you are trying to solve (see http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: the problem is I want the argument to be one token (a variable name, a type, etc.)

Comment: @AbdulmalekAlmkainzi The problem is that you didn't read the XY problem link I pointed you to. What is the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve?